# Rewrite a procedural script in clean OOP Python style

Tags: python, coding-style, wmi, implementation

I've successfully written a Powershell script which:

- query AD to obtain the list of computer
- query every computer through WMI to obtain software/hardware information
- insert the collected data into a MySQL database.

The script works fine but I don't like how it's implemented. It's procedural and there is a lot of code duplication, causing a mess everytime I need to change something.

Now, what I would like to ask you is: what is the cleanest way to implement it in python using OOP? I've thought something similar to this (pseudocode):

```
Class ADquery
    function get_computers( UO ): return a list of computers in the specified UO

Class Computer
    constructor( computername )
    function query(): connect to the computer and pull the info through WMI
    function print(): print the collected info to the console (debug)
    property RAM
    property CPU
    ...
```

Questions:

1. In order to save the collected data into a Database, do I have to create another object (e.g. Database) and pass the Computer object to him or add a member function to the Computer class (e.g. save_db() ) ?
2. If I go for the second option, that wouldn't cause a massive number of MySQL connections when I'm dealing with multiple objects?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad English

Comment: It might be more useful to post your complete script (or critical parts thereof) on http://codereview.stackexchange.com and ask people to improve it.

Comment: thanks @thg435, but I haven't write a single line of the new script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That architecture looks reasonable to me.

1. You could do either, I'm not sure it really makes a huge difference with a small application like this.
2. Potentially. Depending on how it's implemented you could get a lot of connections going on. If you're doing a reasonable number of inserts I'd stick them in a list and insert all at once, if that's possible with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could also grab an Object Oriented Design book from the internet or your local bookstore, e.g. [Rumbaugh et al.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136298419). I would also recommend reading up on Design Patterns, e.g. the book by [Gamma et. al.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612). I'm currently doing that, and it is really helpful to look at standard patterns of how to solve a particular problem to shape your thought process about object oriented programming.

ps Your English isn't bad at all (note that I'm also not a native speaker ;)).

Comment: +1. Good point. I'd recommend that to **any** new or learning developer!

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've just ordered Design Patterns :)

Comment: Good for you! I really like the book